# Simple quadrupole field not yet in Lorenz gauge?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

I'm having trouble reproducing some of the results regarding gravitational waves in the [Wald's General Relativity](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/G/bo5952261.html).

In section 4.4 of gravitational radiation, eq.4.4.49 shows the far-field generated by a variable mass quadrupole:

$$ \gamma_{i j}(t,r)=\frac{2}{3R} \frac{d^2 q_{i j}}{dt^2} \bigg|_{t'=t-R/c} $$

I want to verify that this simple field satisfies the Lorenz gauge (eq.4.4.25)

$$\partial_{i} \gamma_{i j}=0 $$

I wrote the $q_{i j}$ for a simple rotating binary

$
\ddot{q}_{i j} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \omega^2 \cos{2\omega(t-R/c)} & - 2 \omega^2 \sin{2\omega(t-R/c)} & 0 \\
- 2 \omega^2 \sin{2\omega(t-R/c)} & - 2 \omega^2 \cos{2\omega(t-R/c)} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

then, I wrote $R=\big|(x,y,z)\big|$

$\partial_{i} \gamma_{i 3}$ trivially cancels, but when I compute the other components of the divergence I get

$$ \partial_{i} \gamma_{i 1} = \frac{2 \omega^2([-c x+2 y R \omega]\cos{2\omega(t-R/c)}+[c y+2 x R \omega]\sin{2\omega(t-R/c)})}{c R^3} $$

$$ \partial_{i} \gamma_{i 2} = \frac{2 \omega^2([c y+2 x R \omega]\cos{2\omega(t-R/c)}+[c x-2 y R \omega]\sin{2\omega(t-R/c)})}{c R^3} $$

Which as you might have noticed, **are not zero in general**

Given that the Lorenz gauge is used everywhere one wants to study gravitational wave propagation, it seems unexpected that the far-field of a simple binary quadrupole is not automatically in the Lorenz gauge

> **Question:** I want to understand what is wrong here, if there is anything wrong. Am I wrong/naive in expecting this simple field to be
>   in the Lorenz gauge? Is there a simple transformation that can be
>   applied to this field in order to be manifestly in harmonic
>   coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are simply forgetting the $\gamma_{0\mu}$ components of the metric.  As mentioned in Wald, these are to be obtained using the (Lorenz) gauge condition, and are given explicitly in terms of the spatial components of the metric in eq. (4.4.45).

When those components are included in your metric, Lorenz gauge should be manifestly satisfied (by construction).

Comment: in the TT-gauge both the time components and the longitudinal components should vanish. The only example they generally show that matches all the gauge constraints are plane waves, which satisfy the Lorenz gauge by having $k_{\mu} C_{\mu \nu} = 0$, with $C$ being the polarization tensor and $k$ the propagation vector

Comment: In the radiation gauge (as Wald calls it) the $\gamma_{00}$ component vanishes only if there are no sources anywhere in the spacetime (see the remarks between eq. 4.4.33 and 4.4.34. In this case there clearly is a source (the time dependent quadrupole), and $\gamma_{00}$ as follows easily form your calculation and eq. (4.4.45).

Comment: why would the $\gamma_{00}$ component affect the values of $\partial_{i} \gamma_{i1}$ and $\partial_{i} \gamma_{i2}$? Also, As far as I can see, $\gamma_{\mu 0}$ is zero for $\mu=1,2,3$

Comment: The $\gamma_{\mu0}$ components are whatever they need to be in order to make $\partial^\mu\gamma_{\mu0}$ vanish.

Comment: I am quoting 1st paragraph page 80, "in the case of linearized gravity, we can use the restricted gauge freedom, equation (4.4.27), to achieve the radiation gauge $\gamma=0$, $\gamma_{\mu 0}=0$ for $\mu=1,2,3$ in a source free region"

Comment: Please see the parenthetical remark at the end of the paragraph following eq. (4.4.42): "(The radiation gauge conditions, of course, are not imposed since sources are present.)"  Hence the $\gamma_{\mu0}$ are not made to vanish. Instead as explicitly stated by Wald, they are given by eq. (4.4.45).